# constexpr member function with std::vector data member in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am trying to implement in a C++ class a constexpr member function which returns a template parameter. The code is supposed to be c++11 compatible. However I encounter compilation issues when the templated class also contains STL containers as data members such as std::vector (which are untouched by the constexpr member function).

A minimal example is given by the following code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<size_t n>
struct A 
{
    constexpr size_t dimensions() const
    {
        return n;
    }
private:
    std::vector<double> a;
};

 
int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    auto a=A<3>();
    std::array<double,a.dimensions()> arr;
}
```

The code compiles correctly with the commands

`g++ -std=c++14 -O3 quickTest.cpp -o test -Wall`

`clang++ -std=c++11 -O3 quickTest.cpp -o test -Wall`

but fails when I use

`g++ -std=c++11 -O3 quickTest.cpp -o test -Wall`

with the error:

```
quickTest.cpp:22:33: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘size_t A<n>::dimensions() const [with long unsigned int n = 3; size_t = long unsigned int]’
   std::array<double,a.dimensions()> arr;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
quickTest.cpp:10:20: note: ‘size_t A<n>::dimensions() const [with long unsigned int n = 3; size_t = long unsigned int]’ is not usable as a ‘constexpr’ function because:
   constexpr size_t dimensions() const
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
quickTest.cpp:22:33: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘size_t A<n>::dimensions() const [with long unsigned int n = 3; size_t = long unsigned int]’
   std::array<double,a.dimensions()> arr;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
quickTest.cpp:22:33: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’
```

Why does the code not compile with `gcc -std=c++11` but does compile with `clang++ -std=c++11` ?
How could one make this code snippet work with older versions of gcc which may not support c++14/17, but only c++11?

I am using gcc 8.1.1 and clang 6.0.1

Comment: C++14 [Relaxed constexpr restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions) so this is fine. Question is who is right gcc or clang? IMO gcc.

Comment: If you enable more warnings, the compiler tells you the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/hRMsN0 `warning: enclosing class of 'constexpr' non-static member function 'size_t A<n>::dimensions() const [with long unsigned int n = 3; size_t = long unsigned int]' is not a literal type [-Wpedantic]`, `note: 'A<3>' is not literal because: 'A<3>' has a non-trivial destructor` -> It's not about `std::vector` but just about non-trivial destructors.

Comment: Solution is simple: Make `dimensions` a `static` function (and remove the `const`). https://godbolt.org/z/y_YuMU

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++11 had a rule [[dcl.constexpr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.constexpr#8):

> ... The class of which that function is a member shall be a ***literal type*** ([[basic.types]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types#10)).

`struct A` is not a *literal type* because of the `vector`, hence its non-static member functions cannot be `constexpr`.

So GCC is right to reject the code in C++11 mode.

C++14 [removed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.constexpr) that restriction.

The solution for C++11 is to declare `dimensions()` `static`:

```cpp
static constexpr size_t dimensions()
{
    return n;
}
```

[Live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/HV2m63)